# estou como root e els diz que não estou (ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: ubuntu

Após a instalação do ELS (easy linux secutiry) quando vou dar os seguintes comandos:

```
els --update; els --chkrootkit; els --rkhunter; els --chmodfiles; els --disabletelnet; els --hardensysctl; els --libsafe; els --mytop; els ---securepartitions
```

o terminal me volta dizendo q não estou logado como root, E EU ESTOU SIM!!... já tentei executar colocando sudo e tbm diz q não sou root... olhem abaixo:

[image: erro não sou root]

me ajudem por favor, agradeço desde já!

Comment: eu li sua reposta (que como o Guilherem falou deveria ser um comentário), e acho que vale comentar aqui que, segundo o site do [ELS](http://servermonkeys.com/els.php), o programa não é atualizado desde 2009. Então recomendo você procurar outras opções para proteger seu VPS.

Answer (score 1):

Realmente não tenho uma explicação do porque isso ocorre, mas o seguinte fez o comando funcionar para mim:

No **els.sh** instalado (no meu computador ele ficou em **/usr/local/els/**), você vai encontrar o seguinte na linha 86 do código:

```
## Make sure the script is being executed as root
rootcheck() {
   if [ "${UID}" != "0" ]; then
      echo "This program must be run as root.  Exiting."
      exit 0
   fi
}
```

Modifique o `if` para:

```
## Make sure the script is being executed as root
rootcheck() {
   if [ "$(id -u)" != "0" ]; then
      echo "This program must be run as root.  Exiting."
      exit 0
   fi
}
```

Com essa modificação o comando se comporta como esperado:

- Executando como usuário normal:

  ```
  $ els --version
  This program must be run as root.  Exiting.
  ```
- E como root:

  ```
  # els --version
  ELS version is 3.0.0.3. It is the latest release, there is no need to update.
  ```

Comment: E você acha que pode confiar num script que aparentemente não foi feito pra sua distro? (ao menos, depender de ${UID} estar setado corretamente indica isto). Fico imaginando que outras dependências não resolvidas o script pode ter.

Comment: @Bacco sim concordo também, o provável problema deve ser uma falta de `apt-get update` ou `upgrade` e baixou alguma versão errada, ou tentou instalar manualmente, não me parece um problema dentro do escopo da comunidade, acho que a pergunta deve ser fechada e simplesmente isso, o máximo que poderia responder é como instalar a versão atualizada e não como "modificar". Mas não tenho certeza do problema... +1 Bacco pro seu comentário

Comment: Bom, se vocês forem ver a página do ELS http://servermonkeys.com/els.php, vão ver que o programa não é atualizado desde 2009, então ele não foi feito para várias distros :). Ainda assim, se o @DanielFortunato realmente estiver precisando executar esse programa no Ubuntu 14.04, esse é um dirty-quick fix que deixa ele fazer isso. Mas como vocês disseram, não é recomendável.

Comment: nossa brother muito obrigado, resolveu mesmo aki, agora minha VPS está mais segura, vlwww!!